# Using sendEmailVerification with AngularFire

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

Has anyone tried the new Email Verification feature of Firebase 3 with angularfire? I am unable to see any documentation in their github site on its usage - https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no integration of Email verification in AngularFire.

Luckily it is trivial to do this on the regular Firebase SDK for JavaScript:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
```

Also see this [`sendEmailVerification()` method in the Firebase Auth quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/email.html#L109-L145).